# converting integer value of week to datetime

Tags: pandas, datetime, jupyter-notebook, valueerror, forecast

i had a dataset containing week column which is a integer value(1-145), and for forcasting future output(146-155) i need to convert week column to datetime which is (1 to 2021-01-rd)(rd = random date). LIkewise i had around 4 million data in it.

i've tried a method like:
x = 2021
y = str(x) + df.week
[forecast](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ej4KB.png)`dataset`

so that i got df as :
[forecast](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tz96K.png)`converted dataset`

now i applied formula or logic which goes as:
df['week_2'] = pd.to_datetime((df['week_1']-1).astype(str) + "6", format="%Y%U%w")

After this i'm getting an error called:
ValueError: unconverted data remains: 6

please help in the direction i'm going or else suggest another way

Comment: Can you please provide a clear minimal reproducible example (as DataFrame, not image) and the matching expected output

Comment: potentially, you can add the week as a timedelta to a reference date (a week is, in contrast to e.g. a month, still an unambiguous quantity of time / duration).